# split data frame based on integer index

Tags: pandas

In pandas how do I split Series/dataframe into two Series/DataFrames where odd rows in one Series, even rows in different? Right now I am using

```
rng = range(0, n, 2)
odd_rows = df.iloc[rng]
```

This is pretty slow.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use slice:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])

In [12]: s.iloc[::2]  # even
Out[12]:
0    1
2    3
dtype: int64

In [13]: s.iloc[1::2]  # odd
Out[13]:
1    2
3    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Super late but explanation: slice syntax. start(do nothing):stop(do nothing):step_count(2). So for evens you'd start at 0, go to end, increment by 2. For odds, you'd start at 1, go to end, increment by 2.

Answer (score 6):

Here's some comparisions

```
In [100]: df = DataFrame(randn(100000,10))
```

simple method (but I think range makes this slow), but will work regardless of the index
(e.g. does not have to be a numeric index)

```
In [96]: %timeit df.iloc[range(0,len(df),2)]
10 loops, best of 3: 21.2 ms per loop
```

The following require an `Int64Index` that is range based (which is easy to get, just `reset_index()`).

```
In [107]: %timeit df.iloc[(df.index % 2).astype(bool)]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.67 ms per loop

In [108]: %timeit df.loc[(df.index % 2).astype(bool)]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.48 ms per loop
```

make sure to give it index positions

```
In [98]: %timeit df.take(df.index % 2)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.06 ms per loop
```

same as above but no conversions on negative indicies

```
In [99]: %timeit df.take(df.index % 2,convert=False)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.44 ms per loop
```

This winner is @AndyHayden soln; this only works on a single dtype

```
In [118]: %timeit DataFrame(df.values[::2],index=df.index[::2])
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.5 us per loop
```