# Calculate new values from certain rows/columns of dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

So given an example DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Team': ['Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 4',],
    'Data 1': [10, 20, 15, 25,],
    'Data 2': [12, 15, 23, 14,],
})
```

I need to calculate a value and add it into a new column, 'Data 3'.

The logic would be:
df['Data 3'] = if index is odd number, df['Data 1'] + df['Data 2] *at current index + 1*

and then the reverse logic as well:
df['Data 3'] = if index is even number, df['Data 1'] + df['Data 2] *at current index - 1*

The resulting DataFrame should look like (**to be filled by Asker**)

```py
>>> df
     Team  Data 1  Data 2  Data 3
0  Team 1      10      12       _
1  Team 2      20      15       _
2  Team 3      15      23       _
3  Team 4      25      14       _
```

I know there are ways to see if the index is even or odd, but I don't know how much you can fine tune with manipulating the data pull from there.

I may be able to split the DataFrames with the same indexes and doing references that way if this type of logic is just impossible to do.

Comment: please add an example of the resulting DataFrame, I've embedded one you can fill out!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably much faster to [**shift**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) the data up and down to get it aligned for row-wise/vector math (see also [`numpy.roll()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html))

- Use [`.shift()` to roll the Series](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75333055/4541045)
- Take odd and even index ([split data frame based on integer index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457329/split-data-frame-based-on-integer-index))
- Add each Series independently (with the data aligned, `+` is sufficient for the row-wise sums)
- `.add()` the two Series (rather than use `+`) to eliminate intermediate `NaN`s

```py
df["Data 3"] = (df["Data 1"] + df["Data 2"].shift(-1)).iloc[::2]
df["Data 3"] = df["Data 3"].add((df["Data 1"] + df["Data 2"].shift(1)).iloc[1::2], fill_value=0)
```

```
>>> df
     Team  Data 1  Data 2  Data 3
0  Team 1      10      12    25.0
1  Team 2      20      15    32.0
2  Team 3      15      23    29.0
3  Team 4      25      14    48.0
```

---

As a single step (Series)

```
df["Data 1"] + df["Data 2"].shift(-1).iloc[::2].add(df["Data 2"].shift(1).iloc[1::2], fill_value=0)
0    25.0
1    32.0
2    29.0
3    48.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a combination of `.loc` and the `.iterrows()` to iterate over the dataframe and get the data needed to perform the calculations.

```
# List to append calculations to
data3 = []

# Iterate over dataframe
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # If even, no remainder after division by 2
    if (index % 2) == 0:
        # Get relevant data by locating at current index position +1
        calc = df.loc[index+1,"Data 1"] + df.loc[index+1,"Data 2"]
    else:
        # Get relevant data by locating at current index position -1
        calc = df.loc[index-1,"Data 1"] + df.loc[index-1,"Data 2"]

    # Append calculation to list
    data3.append(calc)

# Create new column from list
df["Data 3"] = data3
```

This outputs your desired result:

```
|   |   Team | Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3 |
|--:|-------:|-------:|-------:|-------:|
| 0 | Team 1 |     10 |     12 |     35 |
| 1 | Team 2 |     20 |     15 |     22 |
| 2 | Team 3 |     15 |     23 |     39 |
| 3 | Team 4 |     25 |     14 |     38 |
```

Comment: Now going off of this logic, if the value I need to find is is another dataframe and I need to reference the 'Team' to get the value, is that possible? Trying with loc and map but map doesn't like loc.

Ex: df.loc[index+1, 'Team'].map(dict(zip(df_values['Team'], df_values['Data 1'])))

Comment: @Link apologies I didn't see your comment! Not sure if I can picture what you're getting at - are you trying to map the values from the `Data` columns into a different dataframe (`df_values`), which shares the same `Team` column?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Data 3'] = 2*(df.index%2)-1 + df['Data 1'] + df['Data 2']
```

To solve the problem I will invoke some mathematics - namely modular arithmetic. In the above, `df.index` returns the indexes of the dataframe, i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

Hitting this with a `%2` then takes these numbers and converts them to modular 2 form. Hence, `df.index%2` yields 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, etc. Note that the even indexes return 0 whilst the odd return 1.

Doubling this output and subtracting 1 provides the sequence -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, etc. (take care in that without the brackets you will double first). Notice now that in the positions of the sequence where even numbers originally were we have -1, whilst in the odd positions we have +1.

Bringing this together, the full transformation is `2*(df.index%2)-1`, and if we add this to both `df['Data 1']` and `df['Data 2']` we have our desired result.

The benefits of this approach is firstly, IMO the resulting code is short and elegant in that it fits on in one short line, making it more readable, less bug prone, and easily generalisable to involve more complex manipulations. The second is that it involves relatively few, simple calculations, and I imagine results in relatively short run times (although I have not checked this myself).

Comment: watch out - this probably doesn't give the expected result and simply alternates adding or subtracting `1` from the naive row-wise sum rather than at an offset index!

Comment: @ti7 Unsure what this comment means. Could you please explain?

Comment: I'd misread their Question initially, so it may turn out not to be Answerable (what should the first row contain? so my Answer may not work), but I take "_df['Data 2] at current index + 1_" to be a single statement calling for an offset, not simply the inclusion of a small term! hopefully they'll clarify and fill the example table for us!